# matlab conditioned matrix assignment

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

i have a question about matrix assignment.

say i have three matrices A, B and C, and i want to assign the elements of matrix C to the elements of A and B according to the rule

```
  C[i,j] = A[i,j] if abs(C[i,j] - A[i,j]) < abs(C[i,j] - B[i,j])
  C[i,j] = B[i,j] if abs(C[i,j] - A[i,j]) > abs(C[i,j] - B[i,j])
  C[i,j] = 0  if abs(C[i,j] - A[i,j]) == abs(C[i,j] - B[i,j])
```

how can i write it without for loops?

thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You do realize that matrix indexing in MATLAB does not use [] ? I imagine that will cause you some problems once you ever use the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Dan Becker has the right idea, but re-computing `abs(C-B)` and `abs(C-A)` implies that the *updated* matrices are compared, not the *original* ones.

I don't think this is what you want, so here's the corrected version of his method:

```
CmA = abs(C-A);
CmB = abs(C-B);

ind = Cma < CmB; C(ind) = A(ind);
ind = CmA > CmB; C(ind) = B(ind);
C(CmA == CmB) = 0;
```

Comment: Ah, nice catch - I agree that this is likely what the OP intended! I should perhaps not try to answer SO questions late at night ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want the following:

```
ind = abs(C - A) < abs(C - B) ; C(ind) = A(ind);
ind = abs(C - A) > abs(C - B) ; C(ind) = B(ind);
ind = abs(C - A) == abs(C - B) ; C(ind) = 0;
```

Comment: I agree with Rody Oldenhuis's reply.